# Access entity array by index c#

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have a table that represents a matrix:

```
CustType  DiscountGroup1 DiscountGroup2 DiscountGroup3
Wholesale        32           10               15  
Retail           10           15               0
```

All my stock items have a corresponding discount group code 1, 2 or 3.

At the time of invoicing I want to lookup the discount the customer type gets on the item(s) being invoiced.

The table needs to be able to grow to include new customer types and new discount groups so nothing can be hardcoded.

I figured I would pull the data into an array so I could select the column by index but I am getting stumped by my entities being too intelligent...

```
var disc = (from d in context.CustDiscountGroups
                    where d.CustType == Wholesale
                    select d).ToArray();
```

I can only access the columns by name ie: `disc[0].DiscountGroup1`

if I try `disc[0,1]` I get an error saying wrong number of indices inside.

What am I missing? I feel like it is something ridiculously fundamental. My only other thought was naming the columns as 1, 2, 3 etc and building a sql select string where I can use a variable to denote a column name.

The database is in design stages as well so the table(s) can be remade in any way needed, I'm struggling to get my head wrapped round which way to approach the problem.

Comment: Try [0][1] instead of [0,1]

Comment: @alex Thanks but didn't work. "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'EwhData.CustDiscountGroup'"

Answer (score 0):

your entity `CustDiscountGroups` having properties  `CustType,  DiscountGroup1, DiscountGroup2, DiscountGroup3` and your query return array of  `CustDiscountGroups` so you cant access like `[0,1]` there is no 2D array

if you need to access first item you can get it as `disc[0]` then you can get any of properties of discount group by name of the property.  like

`disc[0].CustType,  disc[0].DiscountGroup1, disc[0].DiscountGroup2, disc[0].DiscountGroup3`

If you want to get array of array then get the property value using reflection as below

```
var disc = context.CustDiscountGroups.Where(c=>c.CustType == Wholesale)
             .Select(v=>typeof(CustDiscountGroups)
                         .GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
                          .Select(f=>f.GetValue(v)).ToArray())
              .ToArray();

var disc = context.CustDiscountGroups.Where(c=>c.CustType == Wholesale)
             .Select(v=>typeof(CustDiscountGroups)
                         .GetProperties()
                          .Select(f=>f.GetValue(v,null)).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

now you can access values like `disc[0][1]`

Please note: I haven't  compiled and tested above code, please get the idea and change as you want

Comment: Thanks @Damith, it's giving me a "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object[] ToArray[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." - I need to hit the books again.